# Add media query inside a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

^^ Hello There !

I need to add media query function inside my Javascript loop.

In fact, when I consult the page from a mobile, the background color is not correctly integrated.

I already add this CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 700px)
and (orientation: portrait) {

.vc_gitem-zone-mini .disponibilite_mh{
    transform:rotate(40deg);
    position:absolute;
    top:-200px;
    left:100px;
    color:white;
    height:30px;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;     }

.mh_list_item{
width:20rem;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0!important;  }
}
```

Below the Javascript code:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("disponibilite_mh");
for (let element of elements) {
    switch (element.innerText) {
        case 'Disponible':
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            break;
        case 'Réservé':
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
            break;
        case 'Vendu':
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            break;
        default:
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            } 
        }
    }

window.onload = changeMediaQuery;

function changeMediaQuery(x) {
if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
window.onload = changeBackgroundColor;
}
else {
return;
}
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
changeMediaQuery(x)
x.addListener(changeMediaQuery)
```

Any idea how to use media queries with javascript in my case?

Please look at Screenshot Computer and Smartphone below:

Smartphone View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Ekd.jpg

Computer View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFJwb.jpg

Thank you for your help ! :3

Comment: There might be better ways, but I often make a div of 0px width and height. I hide it with a CSS media query. Then I can check it's visibility in Javascript. Is the div visible --> no media query applied, desktop view; Is the div not visible --> media query is applied, mobile view.

Comment: Did you help me for code and syntax please?